# eclipse editor issue (jumping to the top)

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have one issue in eclipse, that is infuriating to me. When I'm writing code, very often The editor jumps to the top. Did this happen to someone else?

Just in case it has to do with specific patterns, it happens with this code example:

```
for(i in this._arrayData)
{
    var element = this._arrayData[i];
    if(element.uiElementIndex > indexOfUiElSel)
    {
        nextElement = element;
        break;
    }
}

index_two = this._arrayData[nextElement._id].uiElementIndex;

this._arrayData[elementId].uiElementIndex = index_two;
```

Thanks very much,

Daniel.

Comment: and...what is the issue?

Comment: @Vinayak the editor is _"jumping to the top"_.

Comment: Switch to intellij, it's so much better :) #troll